# Get request is not fulfilling Angular-Express

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, express, angular-http

I'm new to MEAN stack I want to have data fetch from express server (which I created with mongodb) when I click button, the function on button click was executed but request was not fulfilled, the database, server all running fine, I just got nothing at console, here are my client and server files:

- client(running on http://localhost:3001)
- Imported modules and added to imports in ngModule

> import { Http , Headers, HttpModule, Response, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";

Injected in constructor as service,  then:
template:

```
<button md-button class="button1" (click)="newQues()">Submit</button>
```

In class:

```
newQues(){

  this.http.get('https://localhost:3000/')
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);  //these copied from angular2
                                           //official documentation          
}

private extractData(res: Response) {
let body = res.json();
console.log(body);  //not getting console nor error
return body.data || { };
}
```

server running on port 3000

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

   model.findOne({ id: 1}, function (err, data) {
   if (err) {
   console.log(err)
   } else {
   console.log(data);
   res.send(data);
}
})
```

[image]
getting these error when requesting

the whole server code:

```
import * as express from "express";
var app = express();
import * as path from "path";
import * as mongoose from "mongoose";
import * as lodash from "lodash";
import * as morgan from "morgan";


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./../client")));

var uriString = 'mongodb://localhost/quizapp';
mongoose.connect(uriString, function (err, res) {
if (err) {
console.log("Error occured while establishing connection " + err);
} else {
console.log("Connection successful ");
}
})

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({     //schema
question: String,
id: Number
})

var quizz = mongoose.model('Quiz', schema);  //creating model

var firstDoc = new quizz({
question: 'question 1',
id: 1
})
var secondDoc = new quizz({
question: 'question 2',
id: 2
})

var question_data = [firstDoc, secondDoc];

quizz.insertMany(question_data, function (err, res) {
if (err) {
console.log("Error occured while saving document object " + err)
} else {
console.log("Data Saved Successful");
}
})

app.get('/data', function(req, res) {
quizz.findOne({ id: 1}, function (err, data) {
 if (err) {
   console.log(err)
 } else {
   console.log(data);
   res.send(data);   //res.json
 }
 })
 })
```

when I'm routing to localhost:3000/data the data from database displayed on window but when requesting that route from client(see client side code this.http.get) error occurring(picture attached)

Answer (score 0):

for extracting data you have to subscribe to it. try this way

```
export class SimpleHTTPComponent {
      data: Object;
      loading: boolean;

      constructor(public http: Http) {
      }

      makeRequest(): void {
        this.loading = true;
        this.http.request('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
          .subscribe((res: Response) => {
            this.data = res.json();
            this.loading = false;
          });
      }
    }
```

and i think you are not using `this` with `body`. your console.log should be like this. `console.log(this.body);`

Comment: I did subscribe but nothing happend, I think route is not ran at server, or url is not right in get request

Comment: install morgan and i think in place of res.send(data); you should try res.json(data);

Comment: I did nothing happened, also tried to use morgan nothing happened, noting logged

Comment: do one thing.. use postman and see if gives you any output or not. if you don't get output there that means you are doing something wrong in your server code.

Comment: The client side requesting fine, I tried using jsonplaceholder, it returning data, it means client is requesting right, I think there is problem with url and,  route at the server, see the image i attach

Comment: tried postman, got this: This seems to be like an error connecting to http://localhost:3000/. The response status was 0.

Comment: i think you are doing mistake in your server routing file. try with simple app.get('/', function(req, res) { res.send('im the home page!'); }); check your model file. we don't know what have you written there.

Comment: Is it necessary to include headers when requesting using get method?

Comment: according to your server code i don't think you need any access token or any authorization in header.

Comment: show your server code  and i want to know when you requesting any other api on this port no 3000 , is it working or not.